# Django or SQL: finding how many unique values of a given column for an grouped queryset

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, orm

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
member    position
0    1
0    0
0    1
0    1
1    0
1    1
1    0
1    1
1    1
2    0
2    0
2    0
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to know which member(s) only has one position. I've started with SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' GROUP BY member, position
```

and it gives me

```
member    position
0    0
0    1
1    0
1    1
2    0
```

From this result, how can I enucleate all the members that appear only once (members that have only 1 position)? I've tried DISTINCT, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Also, I'd like to write this in Django ORM, with a single queryset, but `group_by` must be used with `annotate` or `aggregate`, but these only work with Sum, Count, Avg... Would that be the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause with `group by`.  Your question is a bit ambiguous.  If you want members with only one `position` *value*:

```
SELECT member
FROM t
GROUP BY member
HAVING MIN(position) = MAX(position);
```

If you want member/position combinations that only occur once:

```
SELECT member, position
FROM t
GROUP BY member, position
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I needed! I edited the question. Now I need to translate this into the ORM but I guess it's better to use another question for that. Thanks a lot!